# Nginx rewrite with Simple Machines Forum

Tags: xml, nginx, rss, url-rewriting, simple-machines-forum

I am running Nginx 1.5.6 and I use the Simple Machines Forum software. Most rewrite rules seem to work properly, with the exception of the RSS feeds.

In my Nginx configuration, I have the following line which is supposed to handle URLs which contain ".xml":

```
rewrite ^/forum/(\.xml|xmlhttp)/?$ "/forum/index.php?pretty;action=$1" last;
```

The above rule produces the following URL for the main forum, which returns a 403 Error:
http://www.mydomain.com/forum/.xml/?type=rss

I would like the rewrite rule to produce this type of URL, which returns code 200 (a real page):
http://www.mydomain.com/forum/?type=rss;action=.xml

I would really appreciate some help to create a rewrite rule to do that. Thanks.

Comment: A few questions. What's `pretty` doing in the rewrites? While, I'm clear about the final rewritten URL, what's the format of source URL that needs to be rewritten? Is it `http://www.mydomain.com/forum/.xml/?type=rss` ?

Comment: Here is the entire block pertaining to the forum rewrites: http://pastebin.com/tZkAibW3